# Как вставить дату?

Tags: php

```
$d = date('Y-m-d');
$result5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `to-1` SET `id_work`='$list3', `id_mesta`='$list4',`Data_poslednego_TO-1`='$d'");
```

В поле `Data_poslednego_TO`-1 вставляются одни нули, поле типа DATE, как вставить дату?

Comment: `Data_poslednego_TO-1` это у вас название поля?

Comment: да, именно так

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `to-1` SET `id_work`='$list3', `id_mesta`='$list4',`Data_poslednego_TO-1`=NOW()
```

Что может делать сервер БД, лучше отдавать ему.

Comment: а как тогда сделать, чтобы допустим вставлял дату на день,месяц, год больше ?

Comment: @3a9 смотрите подобный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544438/select-records-from-now-1-day

Answer (score 1):

В дополнению к ответу. Старайтесь не использовать знаки мат. операций в названиях) И вообще нестандартные символы. для разделения слов нижнего тире вполне хватает.

На тему "дату больше/меньше" - читаем [мануал](http://mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html)